# How to remove all lines after a line that contains a specific string in Bash?

Tags: bash, git

I want to remove all lines after a line which contains the string "Date:" in it. Specifically, I am writing the results of `git show --name-only` to a logging file, but I do not want to log the data after the string that starts with "Date:"

This is the output of `git show --name-only`:

```
commit <commit-hash> (HEAD -> <branch-name>, origin/<branch-name>)
Author: bitbucket-pipelines <commits-noreply@bitbucket.org>
Date:   Mon Sep 18 18:26:04 2023 +0000

    [skip ci] Commit message

logs/log.txt
```

And this is what I want to output:

```
commit <commit-hash> (HEAD -> <branch-name>, origin/<branch-name>)
Author: bitbucket-pipelines <commits-noreply@bitbucket.org>
Date:   Mon Sep 18 18:26:04 2023 +0000
```

I tried to remove lines using specific line numbers and writing to a file and then parsing it there, but I am looking for a solution where I can get the output directly as I want it without any extra steps

Comment: There's lots of ways to do this - please [edit] your question to include what you tried so we can help you with that. Does a solution **need** to key on the string `Date` or could you just print the first 3 lines or the lines before the first empty line or something else?

Comment: Do you want to specifically only remove lines after a line contiaining `Date:` __or__ do you want to print `git show` a commit without the commit message and file changes? Are you asking XY question? Did you read `man git show`? In particular there is `git show --format=`.

Comment: I think the question explains very clearly what is wanted, with example input and output.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do this with only Git by providing the format with which the commit should be printed.

```
git show -s --pretty='commit %H%d%nAuthor: %aN <%aE>%nDate:   %ad'
```

- `%H` the commit hash
- `%d` ref names like `--decorate`
- `%aN` author name (respecting `.mailmap`)
- `%aE` author email (respecting `.mailmap`)
- `%ad` author date

See the [PRETTY FORMATS section of `git help log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_pretty_formats) for a detailed explanation.

---

If you don't want to use Git to control the output format, [`head -3`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/head.1.html) is usually a pretty simple way to get only the first three lines of any output.

Comment: Note that this works for the example input and output, but doesn't answer the more general title question of "How to remove all lines after a line that contains a specific string in Bash?".

Comment: @remcycles that's correct, but the question body states »Specifically, I am writing the results of git show --name-only to a logging file, but I do not want to log the data after the string that starts with "Date:"«, so the question is in fact about producing the correct Git output. OP has to decide which reply answers their question best by accepting one.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Awk.  This will print all lines, and if the line starts with `Date:` the script will exit after printing.

```
git show --name-only | awk '{print} ; /^Date:/ { exit }'
```

Or Sed (quit when line matches):

```
git show --name-only | sed '/^Date:/q'
```

Or if you want to explicitly specify a number of lines:

```
git show --name-only | awk '{print} ; NR==3 { exit }'
git show --name-only | head -n 3
```

For fun, a pure Bash solution (`so_77123710.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash

while true ; do
    read line
    echo "$line"
    if [[ "$line" =~ "Date:" ]] ; then
        exit
    fi
done
```

```
git show --name-only | ./so_77123710.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git show --name-only --no-patch | grep -v '^   .*' | grep -v '^$'
```

`--no-patch` to remove file-change lines (stat). Inverted greps to remove empty and indented lines, which is the message part.

A bit overkill for `git show` but can also be used for `git log`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the good old `grep`! Here I use regex to match and print lines starting with `commit`, `Author:`, and `Date:`.

```bash
git show --name-only | grep '^\(commit\|Author:\|Date:\)'
```